# How to use multiple outputs over time?

Tags: verilog, hardware

I am designing a four bit adder and I wish to test the circuit with three inputs, a,b and op. I am trying to change these  inputs over time so I can get waveforms with active hdl, however I only ever get the last result. In this case, a = 1111 and b = 0000 and never a = 0001 and b = 0000. How can I change these values over time?

```
initial begin
a = 4'b0001;
b = 4'b0000;

op = 3'b010;
#1;  

a = 4'b1111;
b = 4'b0000;

op = 3'b010;   
#1;
end
```

Comment: How are you observing the result? what happens if you use '#100' instead?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I have the registers and wires hooked up to a waveform generator in active HDL. if I use #100, I get the same results

Comment: Can you show the wave form with the inputs your driving and the output from the block. also including the code for the block your applying the stimulus to would be useful. at present there is not enough information to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I cant get a wave form. That's why I am asking this question. The code works correctly. I am simply asking how to change values over time so that I may actually have multiple results in the waveforms and not just a straight line. because the code above does not do that.

Comment: You can not get a wave form or the values do not change in the waveform? Because the inputs do change over time thats what your initial block does. Also why I suggested making it `#100` so that they would be easier to see in a wave form. Do you end the sim with a `$finish();`that should tell the simulators to flush all data to file, which might be required with such a short sim. There is nothing wrong with what you have shown so far, you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple testbench,

```
initial 
begin
  repeat(2)
  begin
      a = $random;
      b = $random;
      op = $random;
      #1;
  end
  #100 $finish;
end
```

Just change number 2 to as per your wish and you'll get that much test vectors generated.

It is not answer of your question but you can increase number of vectors from above code, please change your timescale too.

Comment: It is not different, It is efficient way to generate multiple vectors, in structured way.

Comment: Your correct but the question was about why it was not working. I dare bet if OP set it to repeat 1000 times they might actually start to see some wave forms, but not sure this directly answers the question in part because the question is missing enough information to know what the issues is.

Comment: Yes, the question requires more clarification, exactly how stimulated system made up of.